# SQL Server a trigger to work on multiple rows updated

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem with trigger which I use for procedure implementation. I use inserted table to collect all rows which user updated and procure procedure. But procedure repeat for ech row separately. How to handle this?

my trigger:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[FormUpdate] 
 ON [dbo].[FORM]
   For UPDATE
AS 

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    select * into #inserted from (
    SELECT i.* from FORM gw
    inner join inserted i on  gw.FORMID = i.FORMID) t
     WHERE t.PREPARING <> 0


    IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #inserted) > 0
    BEGIN
        UPDATE GW 
        SET PREPARING = 0
        FROM FORM GW
            INNER JOIN #inserted on GW.FORMID = #inserted.FORMID

    EXEC dbo.PREPARING_OF_THE_FORM

    END
END
```

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve here? Are you wanting to run `EXEC dbo.PREPARING_OF_THE_FORM` for every row that is inserted?  If so, should `dbo.PREPARING_OF_THE_FORM` not have some kind of parameter? Why are you inserting the row from `inserted` into `#inserted`; why not just work within `inserted`? YOur statement of *"But procedure repeat for ech row separately. How to handle this?"* isn't true, a trigger only "triggers" once, regardless of if the DML operation affects 1, 2, 500, or 1Million+ rows.

Comment: what is in `dbo.PREPARING_OF_THE_FORM`

Comment: dbo.PREPARING_OF_THE_FORM is using inserted table rows for copy to other table with aditional remarks and columns.

Comment: My intention is to collect updated rows from inserted table as a one set of rows and provide as a set of tese rows to procedure to next processing

Comment: This has all the telltale signs of being an [xy problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 0):

I may be way off but i think i am pretty close.

As it looks right now the Form table is updated and then the stored procedure runs. I am guessing the stored procedure runs some work on the form table. If you want to run it on every row it looks like (i hate to say it) you need a CURSOR.

You will need to create a cursor from your first select something like

```
 select * into #inserted from (
SELECT i.* from FORM gw
inner join inserted i on  gw.FORMID = i.FORMID) t
 WHERE t.PREPARING <> 0

DECLARE CURSOR inserted_Cursor
FOR

SELECT * 
FROM #inserted

OPEN inserted_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM inserted_cursor

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN 
    UPDATE GW 
    SET PREPARING = 0
    FROM FORM GW
        INNER JOIN #inserted on GW.FORMID = #inserted.FORMID
EXEC dbo.PREPARING_OF_THE_FORM

FETCH NEXT FROM inserted_cursor
END

CLOSE inserted_cursor
DEALLOCATE inserted_Cursor
```

I haven't had a chance to test this so it may take some fiddling to get it to run. I am not sure what the stored procedure is doing but you will need to make sure it can handle one record at a time. It may be best to not use the stored procedure and just write out the code to ensure it can handle the one row at a time.

Also keep in mind there are better ways to do this but with your specific application and without knowing the architecture this is what i think the best solution for you.

Comment: Wes Palmer thank you very much. Unfortunately it doesn’t work. Even If I use local cursor I receive not satisfied result - all rows still are treated separately. I am afraid I have to rebuild total design of solution.

Comment: Is the stored procedure meant to execute once after all the values are inserted?

Comment: @Anna Is the stored procedure meant to execute once after the values are inserted into the table?

Comment: yes you are right, store procedure is executed after updated rows in table

Comment: I think if you pull the stored procedure outside of the if statement you will get the results you are looking for.